# Calculate pdf of distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

I have a normal distribution how can I calculate pdf(probability density function) value from it

```
#Distribution
from scipy import stats
Distribution = stats.norm(10, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from scipy import stats

def pdf(x):
    return Distribution.pdf(x)

pdf(10)
```

--> 0.04432692004460363

Comment: Where did you get value of 10 from pdf(10 )? from the distribution?